# How to fix: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, timezone

I receive this error from AWS:

> App\Services\Exceptions\Exception thrown with message "Error in
>   updated facebook event in the systemError executing "PutObject" on
>   "n.jpg"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: PUT n.jpg resulted in a 403
>   Forbidden response:
>       
>       `RequestTimeTooSkewed`The difference between the reque (truncated...)
>     RequestTimeTooSkewed (client): The difference between the request time and the current time is too large. - 
>       `RequestTimeTooSkewed`The difference between the request time and the current time is too
>   large.20180403T075710Z2018-04-03T06:57:48Z900000"

It says request time is: `7:57 am` and server time is: `6:57 am`.

However my local machine time is: `9:57 am` (not using vagrant or any server).

and my AWS is in Ohio where the time is: `2:57 am`.

What do I change to fix this error ?

I'm building a `php/Laravel 5.5` project.

Comment: Surely this is just a timezone fix? You can adjust the timezone within the config/app.php file

Comment: It is set to my local time which is same as my local machine. I'll double check though. thnx.

Comment: Generally, changing the timezone within your app.php will save the correct times to your database too. Double check you havent mistyped or anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It says request time is: 7:57 am and server time is: 6:57 am.

**Server time** means the time at the AWS Server (S3).

> and my AWS is in Ohio where the time is: 2:57 am.

This doesn't matter.  AWS runs on Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).  The servers in the various regions don't know what the time is, where they are.

**Request time** means the timestamp encoded into the request, generated wherever the code is running -- presumably your desktop/laptop in this case.  It is coded in UTC.

> However my local machine time is: 9:57 am (not using vagrant or any server).

Generally speaking, computers -- operating systems -- have two concepts that interact to answer the question of "what time is it?" --

- what time is it now? *and*
- what offset should I use when displaying times to the user?  The offset is the time zone setting.

Both of these need to be correct... otherwise, your clock can simultaneously:

- be set to the wrong time *and*
- display the correct time

Your computer believes its clock is set to display the correct local time for a time zone that is UTC+2... so it is subtracting 2 hours from the displayed "local" time when signing the request (display 9:57, request time 7:57)... but if 9:57 am is your local time, then your time zone setting on your computer is incorrect, because you are actually in UTC+3, because the "server" (at Amazon) has the time showing as 6:57.

Correcting your time zone setting and then adjusting the clock by one hour (if necessary) should resolve the issue.

Comment: NTP does not use timezones or DST.

Answer (score 6):

You need to update the time on the AWS server and Local machine. Best way to do is to run `ntpdate` command to sync time.

Command:

```
sudo ntpdate -u in.pool.ntp.org
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I turned on Day Light Saving on my system and tried again and it worked. I turned off the Day Light Saving because makes the time over here late by 1 hour.

Depending on where you are on the planet, what worked for me is to reduced my system time by 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

How I fixed issue for me:

1. On the host machine where docker-daemon/docker is running. Install ntp

   ```
   yum -y install ntp
   ```
2. Add NTP Server

   ```
   ntpdate -u in.pool.ntp.org
   ```

When host system time is correct (after syncing it with NTP servers) containers will auto-correct the time.

Answer (score 0):

On some systems, NTP will not set the local clock if the offset exceeds the "panic threshold", which is typically 1000 secs.  As mentioned in the comments, the **ntpdate command is probably best way** to deal with this.  Or the local clock can be manually set.  But if you do it that way, you'll ideally need to ensure the offset is less than the "step threshold", which is typically only 0.128secs or 0.125secs.  Otherwise, it probably will take about 900 secs (the typical "stepout threshold") to sync via a clock step.  Normally, it takes about oly 240 secs to sync, and there should be no hard step.  Or you can disable this "safety" feature.  Beware "stepping" (vs slowly "disciplining") the clock, especially backwards, can cause issues.